# How to use object entries as indices into a nested object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use object entries as indices into a nested object like this:

```js
type Size = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
type Variant = 'primary' | 'secondary';

const styles: {
  size: Record<Size, object>;
  variant: Record<Variant, object>;
} = {
  size: {
    small: { padding: 8 },
    medium: { padding: 12 },
    large: { padding: 16 },
  },
  variant: {
    primary: { background: 'hotpink' },
    secondary: { background: 'silver' },
  },
};

const props: { size: Size; variant: Variant } = {
  size: 'medium',
  variant: 'primary',
};

const css = (Object.keys(props) as Array<keyof typeof props>).reduce(
  (acc, key) => {
    const value = props[key];
    return { ...acc, ...styles[key][value] };
    //                  ^ Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
    // expression of type '"small" | "medium" | "large" | "primary" | "secondary"'
    // can't be used to index type 'Record<Size, object> | Record<Variant, object>'
  },
  {}
);
```

I am using `as Array<keyof typeof ...>` to avoid `Object.keys` just giving `string[]` keys -- but I'm not sure what then to do with the resulting union type?